# Why am I getting the 'delegate_to' is not a valid attribute for a Play error in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I pulled the code from the ansible docs site [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/vmware_guest_module.html#examples).

```
- name: Create a virtual machine on given ESXi hostname
  vmware_guest:
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
    validate_certs: no
    folder: /DC1/vm/
    name: test_vm_0001
    state: poweredon
    guest_id: centos64Guest
    # This is hostname of particular ESXi server on which user wants VM to be deployed
    esxi_hostname: "{{ esxi_hostname }}"
    disk:
    - size_gb: 10
      type: thin
      datastore: datastore1
    hardware:
      memory_mb: 512
      num_cpus: 4
      scsi: paravirtual
    networks:
    - name: VM Network
      mac: aa:bb:dd:aa:00:14
      ip: 10.10.10.100
      netmask: 255.255.255.0
      device_type: vmxnet3
    wait_for_ip_address: yes
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: deploy_vm
```

When I save the text to a file and try to run it, i get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are pasting the code as a  playbook, but it's a task.

Try changing the file to the following. Please double check the spacing, as yml is *space sensitive* and I haven't tried this script myself. You'll also need to provide some variables to be replaced such as `vcenter_hostname`.

```
---
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Create a virtual machine on given ESXi hostname
      vmware_guest:
        hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
        validate_certs: no
        folder: /DC1/vm/
        name: test_vm_0001
        state: poweredon
        guest_id: centos64Guest
        # This is hostname of particular ESXi server on which user wants VM to be deployed
        esxi_hostname: "{{ esxi_hostname }}"
        disk:
        - size_gb: 10
        type: thin
        datastore: datastore1
        hardware:
        memory_mb: 512
        num_cpus: 4
        scsi: paravirtual
        networks:
        - name: VM Network
        mac: aa:bb:dd:aa:00:14
        ip: 10.10.10.100
        netmask: 255.255.255.0
        device_type: vmxnet3
        wait_for_ip_address: yes
      delegate_to: localhost
      register: deploy_vm
```

Code taken from the [Ansible Docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#basics)

I'm not sure if you'll need to create an [inventory file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html) for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I guess I need to keep reading up. Kinda disappointed that yaml files are so sensitive to spacing.

Answer (score 0):

in file playbook/vm.yml :

```
- hosts: all
  roles:
    - { role: vmdeletion, tags: ['vmdeletion'], when: remove_vm }
    - { role: vmcreation, tags: ['vmcreation'] }
    - { role: vmpower,    tags: ['vmpower'], power: "poweredon" }
```

in file roles/vmcreation/tasks/main.yml :

```
    - name: Create a virtual machine on given ESXi hostname
      vmware_guest:
        hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
        username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
        password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
        validate_certs: no
        folder: /DC1/vm/
        name: test_vm_0001
        state: present
        guest_id: centos64Guest
        # This is hostname of particular ESXi server on which user wants VM to be deployed
        esxi_hostname: "{{ esxi_hostname }}"
        disk:
        - size_gb: 10
          type: thin
          datastore: datastore1
        hardware:
          memory_mb: 512
          num_cpus: 4
          scsi: paravirtual
        networks:
        - name: VM Network
          mac: aa:bb:dd:aa:00:14
          ip: 10.10.10.100
          netmask: 255.255.255.0
          device_type: vmxnet3
        wait_for_ip_address: yes
      delegate_to: localhost
      register: deploy_vm
```

then run :

```
ansible-playbook playbook/vm.yml -l ${my_groups_or_hosts_limit}
```

but try to put all your variables in inventory associated to your hosts/groups, so that your role looks like :

in file roles/vmcreation/tasks/main.yml :

```
- name: Create a virtual machine on given ESXi hostname
  vmware_guest:
    hostname: "{{ vcenter_hostname }}"
    username: "{{ vcenter_username }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_password }}"
    validate_certs: no
    folder: "{{ vm_folder }}"
    name: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    state: present
    guest_id: centos64Guest
    # This is hostname of particular ESXi server on which user wants VM to be deployed
    esxi_hostname: "{{ vm_esxi_hostname }}"
    disk: "{{ vm_disks }}"
    hardware: "{{ vm_hardware }}"
    networks: "{{ vm_networks }}"
    wait_for_ip_address: yes
  delegate_to: localhost
  register: deploy_vm
```